# Rudin Functional Analysis Chapter 4 Problem 6

Tags: functional-analysis, adjoint-operators

Let $\sigma$ and $\tau$ be the weak$^*$-topologies of $X^*$ and $Y^*$ respectively, and prove that $S$ is continuous linear mapping of $(Y^*,\tau)$ into $(X^*,\sigma)$ if and only if $S=T^*$ for some $T\in \text B(X,Y).$

I didn't get that how to approach it when i assume some continuous linear mapping $S$ on $(Y^*,\tau)$.

Any type of help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The gist is that you need to construct a bounded operator $T:X\to Y$ satisfying, for all $\eta\in Y^*$ and all $x\in X$, the relation $\eta(Tx) = (S\eta)(x)$. I don't have Rudin on hand, but I'd go looking for a theorem that lets you pick out vectors with functionals; this will let you define the map $x\to Tx$ by saying something like "$x$ maps to the unique $Tx\in Y$ such that for all $\eta\in Y^*$ we have $(S\eta)(x) = \eta(Tx)$." Then it should be straightforward to check continuity.

Answer (score 1):

For each $x\in X$, the map $y^*\mapsto \langle x,Sy^*\rangle$ is a $\tau$-continuous linear functional on $Y^*$.  Since the dual of $(Y^*,\tau)$ is $Y$, there is some $Tx\in Y$ such that $\langle Tx, y^*\rangle=\langle x,Sy^*\rangle$.  This gives us a mapping $T:X\to Y$ given by $x\mapsto Tx$.  Linearity of $T$ is easy to check.  To show $T$ is continuous, show that it maps norm-bounded sets in $X$ to norm-bounded sets in $Y$.